# mixed effect model in R with unstructured covariance

Tags: mixed-model, lme4-nlme, repeated-measures

### Can the following SAS model be fit in R?

### proc mixed data = df;
class grp week;
model y = grp week grp*week / ddfm = km;
repeated week / subject type = un r;
run;

### The data df is of the following format (actual data contains more obs

> df

## A tibble: 12 × 4

subject grp    week       y
        
1       1 grp1      2      0.692
2       1 grp1      4      1.63
3       1 grp1      6      2.46
4       3 grp1      2      0.753
5       3 grp1      4      1.48
6       3 grp1      6      1.94
7       2 grp2      2      0.356
8       2 grp2      4      0.637
9       2 grp2      6      1.03
10       4 grp2      2      0.596
11       4 grp2      4      0.907
12       4 grp2      6      1.48

Thanks very much!

Comment: Thanks so much for the answer. I usually use lme4 package for fitting mixed models in R. But I struggled to find a way to specify unstructured correlation for repeated measures using lmer. Is there a recommended reading that give a clear and concise  summary on how to specify difference mixed effect models using nlme?

Comment: One more question, before specifying the gls model as you did below, besides setting week as a factor, it is necessary to set id as a factor as well, right?

Comment: No, that is not needed afaik, you could try.

Comment: Btw I feel your question would be more interesting for readers if you would ask about  how to choose a suitable structure, and which statistical measures exist, if any, that help one choosing. I.e. there are different patterns than only the unstructired.

Comment: ok. Agree that is more useful. Thanks a lot!!

Comment: I think this is what the OP means: I agree it's more useful to everyone else on CV if I were to spend effort writing my question (perhaps commensurate with the effort spend to answer it) but @BenP already answered it, so why bother.

Comment: Sorry, what is "weeknr" referring to in the model below? Should it be "weekf" instead?

Comment: No, I just wanted to point out that it must start with 1, then 2 etc

Comment: @BenP Understood. Thanks! I will modify my post as you suggested soon when I get a chance. I appreciate your answer!

Answer (score 1):

Although the question is formulated as a programming/syntax problem I will answer it, because I'm not sure if you are aware of the many other options to model (co)variance matrices over "weeks". And also because I've struggled quite a while myself to figure out the (many) possibilities of package "nlme" and those of "gls", which is often a great alternative for random effect models, in case of longitudinal data.

Before giving the syntax, a "warning". Are you sure you need un unstructed covariance pattern, which is quite parameter-consuming? There are many other structures in the "gls" procedure from "nlme" which you could consider. Also you "should" study your correlations and variances over "weeks", how they differ, if these differences make sense to you. And for any "structure" you choose, compare the variances and correlations over the weeks as produced by the model with the ones you observed for your data. Do the model-produced variances and correlations make sense to you and are they in line with the observed ones? But you may know all this, why am I telling you this (probably because it's a rainy sunday morning).

It's been a while since I used SAS, but I'll give it a shot. You could use "gls" from package "nlme" to do this. Let's say your data are in data frame "da". Variable "week" should be an integer variable running from 1,2,3, ... etc. If not, make a new one, with name "weeknr"e.g. It's important that this new variable "weeknr" is integer valued and starting at value 1, not zero! For the interaction you must have a factor for week.

I would start with a model without "grp", to first study the variances and correlations over the weeks.

```
da$weekf <- factor(da$week)
mymodel <- gls(y ~ weekf, 
               correlation = corSymm(form = ~ weeknr|id),
               weights = varIdent(form = ~1|weeknr), data=da)  
summary(mymodel)
```

The summary shows the effects of the week-dummies, how they differ. To see the variances and correlations produced by the gls model, you can use a script, which I will put at the end of this answer. Before running your "full" model, I would first choose the right pattern for the variances / correlation over the weeks, not only look at the "unstructured" pattern. Use AIC and BIC to compare the different structures in terms of "fit", and use theory/common sense to judge if the model predicted vars and corrs are in line with your (theoretical) expectations.

Then to your "full" model:

```
mymodel <- gls(y ~ grp*weekf, 
               correlation = corSymm(form = ~ weeknr|id),
               weights = varIdent(form = ~1|weeknr), data=da)  
summary(mymodel)
```

To see the model-produced variances and correlations, here is a R script that you must run first, and next you can use:

corandcov.gls(mymodel)

That's it!

R script for shown variances and correlations over time for gls models.

```
# corandcov_gls
#
# Function found on the internet for showing (co)variances and 
# correlations for a generalised least squares (GLS) model 
# estimated with gls form nlme package.
# To call the function use:
#
# corandcov_gls(modelname)
#
# where "modelname" is the name of the GLS model you estimated.
#--------------------------------------------------------------

corandcov.gls <- function(glsob, cov = TRUE, ...) {
  
  corm <- nlme::corMatrix(glsob$modelStruct$corStruct)[[5]]
  
  varstruct <- glsob$modelStruct$varStruct
  
  if (!is.null(varstruct)) {
  varests <- stats::coef(varstruct, uncons = FALSE, allCoef = TRUE)
  covm <- corm * glsob$sigma ^ 2 * t(t(varests)) %*% t(varests)
  
  return(list(correlation_matrix = corm,
         variance_structure = varstruct,
         covariance_matrix = covm))
  }
  
  if (is.null(varstruct)) {
    # The homogeneous variance models CS, AR1 en Toep only have 1 variance
    # and no varStruct which equal NULL then.
    var <- getVarCov(glsob)[1,1]
    list(correlation_matrix = corm, variance = var)
  }
}
```